# Using `evaluate` function. Why it doesn't work?

Tags: groovy, eval

This code:

```
evaluate ("def test() { println \"Test is successful!\" }")
test()
```

results in exception:

> FATAL: No signature of method: script1409644336796288198097.test() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), getAt(java.lang.String), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long)
>   groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script1409644336796288198097.test() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
>   Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), getAt(java.lang.String), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), wait(long)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
>   ...

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't think you can define methods/variables in a Gstring and then call them outside of the scope of that GString. What are you trying to do? There is probably a better way of doing it than this.

Comment: @jk47, why not? I need to read a method definition from text file and execute it.

Comment: You want to write a program that reads in any arbitrary function and then executes it? Why?

Comment: @jk47, because I need to execute that function and can't add file with that function to any directory specified in classpath.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That script evaluation results in null. You should either return something or execute the script and return the result.

An example returning a closure instead of defining a method:

```
test = evaluate ('return { "Test is successful!" }')
assert test() == "Test is successful!"
```

And an example where the script executes the method itself:

```
result = evaluate 'def test() { "eval test" }; return test()'
assert result == "eval test"
```

If you cannot change the script code, you may [parse a class from the script](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy), create a new object, and then execute the `test()` method:

```
def parent = getClass().getClassLoader()
def loader = new GroovyClassLoader(parent)
def clazz = loader.parseClass('def test() { "new class definition" }');

obj = clazz.newInstance()
assert obj.test() == "new class definition"
```

Comment: any way to pass parameters into callee using one of first 2 methods?

Comment: @user626528 oops, sorry for the delay. You can pass parameters using the [`binding`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy).

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. Found I could change this slightly to load methods from an arbitrary file not necessarily in the classpath using this syntax: loader.parseClass(new File("--path to file--"))

Answer (score 2):

If a variable has an undeclared type, then [it goes into the script binding](http://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_variables).  The binding is visible to all methods which means data is shared.

[`evaluate()` is a helper method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate(java.lang.String)) to allow the dynamic evaluation of groovy expressions using `this` scripts binding as the variable scope.

In a variable binding, you can [declare a closure](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#implicit-it) which accepts no argument and must be restricted to calls without arguments.

With all of that in mind, here is your script working as intended.

```
evaluate ("test = { -> println \"Test is successful!\" }")
test()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the ExpandoMetaClass to add dynamic closures to your own class. You would need to parse the string beforehand to split it into function name, arguments and code.

```
methodName = "test"
methodArgs = []
methodCode = """println "Hello World!" """

this.metaClass."$methodName"{ code, args ->
  evaluate(code)
}
```

Then you can call it by doing:

```
"$methodName"(code, arguments)
```

or

```
test(code, arguments)
```

To get the output `Hello World!`

You can read more about ExpandoMetaClass here http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass

Answer (score 1):

In addition to all other answers, if you don't want to change the structure of your code you can simply use `return this` at the end of your groovy-string:

```
lib = evaluate ("def test() { println \"Test is successful!\" }; return this")
lib.test()
```