# Import groovy class in a pipeline Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I need to be able to create classes and use them within a Jenkins pipeline.

Let's say I have a very simple groovy class, declared in a groovy script, looking as this:

```
class MyClass {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "toto";
    }

}
return MyClass();
```

This class is located in the folder: `Project\Buildfiles\Jenkins\com\external`

Then in my Jenkinsfile I would do:

```
node('mynode') {
   toto = load 'Project\Buildfiles\Jenkins\com\external\MyClass.groovy'
   echo toto.toString()
}
```

And this actually **works**

However this do pose a certain numbers of issues with my IDE which does not understand what is happening. Also, this prevents me to have several constructor in my custom class.

What I have been trying to do, and for which I need help, is the following. In a file named `ExternalClasses.groovy`:

```
class Toto{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "toto";
    }

}

class Tata{

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "tata";
    }

}

return this;
```

In the JenkinsFile:

```
node('mynode') {
   external= load 'Project\Buildfiles\Jenkins\com\external\ExternalClasses.groovy'
   toto = new Toto();
   tata = new Tata();
}
```

And this **fails**
I have tried several approaches, used packages names, used the Toto.new() syntax, but none worked.

Any ideas ?

Edit about Shared Libraries:

I actually have a Shared library, it is used by several teams and contains very specific data which should be own by the teams and not by the library.

We need to be able to put out of the library things which does not belong to it. The purpose of this work is to alleviate the said library of non generic code.

Comment: create each class in its own .groovy file

Comment: I put all such reusable code in "global-pipeline-library".  https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: mbn217: Would it allow me to use the "new" keyword and declare several constructors ? Because I currently have one script per class, but it has to return itself at the end.

Comment: Groovy offers different approaches. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25618554/using-evaluate-function-why-it-doesnt-work.
Not sure if they work in Jenkins, since the Groovy Interpreter in Jenkins is modified.

Comment: Please check the path with echo new File('Project\Buildfiles\Jenkins\com\external\ExternalClasses.groovy')

Comment: Any update on this? I am trying the same thing, although was not able to call a customizedClass from a shared library..

Comment: No, you just can't do it. You have to stick with the first solution or use a shared library.

Also, a good solution to my problem would have been to use yaml and a deserialized in a shared library, not creating classes in a repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Shared Library Feature](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/). Upload your scripts into a VCS like Github/Bitbucket and use Jenkins-Jobs to execute them. They are available for all projects/jobs.

Comment: Thank you, I actually have a Shared library, it is used by several teams and contains very specific data which should be own by the teams and not by the library. We need to be able to put out of the library things which does not belong to it.